# how can I run functions by sequential in firebase request to get one single completion

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, firebase

Actually, this is not a complex logic but I'm confused a little bit.

I'm getting user IDs from collection called "following" on my firebase (firestore) and adding an array, and then I'm getting posts those users from another collection called "posts" with "fetchPosts" func. At the end, I'm putting these posts to an array and sending via completion handler. This is what I want.

However I need use closures and functions for this. When I use this functions these are not running sequential so completion is returning empty value.

I tried DispatchQueue group logic (enter, leave etc.), OperationQueues but I couldn't find a solution. maybe I couldn't use right way I'm not sure so I'm open different mindset and algorithm logic.

I want to run following functions sequential.

part 1 > part 2 > part 3 > part 4 and then part 5 (completion)

I mean e.g. I want to run part 3 after part 1 and part 2 are finished. I want to run completion after all of them finished. But it is working like this now:

part 1 > part 1 > part 5 > part 2 > part 2 . . .

If I put these functions in each other, it returns more than one completion. I don't want it because I will use pagination logic after solving this issue.

I understand that this is about threading but I couldn't handle it. How can I run this parts sequential.

This is my code:

```
guard let cuid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid as? String else { return }

let firestoreDatabase = Firestore.firestore()

firestoreDatabase.collection("following").document(cuid).getDocument(source: .server) { document, error in
    
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        
        guard let userIdsDictionary = document.data() as? [String : Int] else {return}
        
        // part 1
        userIdsDictionary.forEach { (key, value) in
            
            self.getUsername(uid: key) { uName in
                
                // part 2
                self.userNamesDictFollowingVC.append(uName)
            }
        }        
        
        // part 3
        self.userNamesDictFollowingVC.forEach { uName in            
            
            self.fetchPosts(username: uName) { postList in                
                
                // part 4
                self.postList.append(contentsOf: postList)
            }
        }        
        
        // part 5 (the last one)
        completion(self.postList)        
    }    
}
```

Comment: You need to nest the code in the completion handler; perform task 2 inside the completion handler for task 1 and so on. If you can use async/await this will be much simpler and cleaner.

Comment: thank you so much. I will try by nested with async await. thank you again.

Comment: If you use async/await then you don't need to nest completion handlers. There aren't completion handlers.